# How to convert ArrayList<Object> to ArrayList<different Object>

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist

I put some value to ArrayList<"Object">

```
ArrayList<Object> mData = new ArrayList<Object>();
AdListData data = new AdListData();
data.Id = json_data.getInt("ad_uid");
data.User_id = json_data.getInt("user_id");
mData.add(data);
```

And after I need to convert ArrayList<"Object"> to ArrayList<"AdListData">
How can I do this? Example:

```
ArrayList<AdListData> array = new ArrayList<AdListData>();
array = mData;
```

Why I need to do this? I use AsyncTask and on onPostExecute a get data like this

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Object> result) {
    // Pass the result data back to the main activity

mDownloadCompleteListener.getDownloadCompleteState(result);
}
```

this example show that a get only on type of arraylist

```
ArrayList<Object>
```

OR

```
ArrayList<AdListData>
```

But in my case I want to use it for different Objects like this

```
ArrayList<Object> mData = new ArrayList<Object>();
if(mType == "get_ad_data")
{

  AdListData data = new AdListData();
  data.Id = json_data.getInt("ad_uid");
  data.User_id = json_data.getInt("user_id");
  mData.add(data);
}
else
{
  AnotherClass data = new AnotherClass();
  data.Id = json_data.getInt("ad_uid");
  data.User_id = json_data.getInt("user_id");
  mData.add(data);
}

return mData;
```

`
And when listener call I want to convert it in needed Array of objects

```
@Override
public void getDownloadCompleteState(ArrayList<Object> ad_list) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<AdListData> array = new ArrayList<AdListData>();
            array = ad_list;
}
```

Comment: Why not initially use `ArrayList<AdListData> mData = new ArrayList<AdListData>()`. What need is there to have mData an Object type if you are going to have it as AdListData anyway?

Comment: The problem is that the way you want to use the `ArrayList` sort of defeats the purpose of generics in the first place -- compile time type checking/safety. A better solution would be to define an interface/superclass of both `AdListData` and `AnotherClass` and use that as your generic type.

Comment: Also, do `getDownloadCompleteState()` and `onPostExecute()` HAVE to take `ArrayList<Object>` as their arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out java generics.  When you pass in your array list, define it as `ArrayList<T extends Object>` or `ArrayList<? extends Object>`.  Then when you're passing or getting values you can define T as the class of your choice or check if the object is an instance of the class you want.  There's a ton of information and examples on java generics so you can find what fits your needs w/o me posting a bunch of examples.

I don't think it's possible to just automatically assign `ArrayList<Object>` to `ArrayList<AdListData>` since there is no guarantee that all of the data is of type `AdListData`.

Comment: Isn't the `<T/? extends Object>` implicit in any unbounded generic type anyways?

Comment: Yeah but at least it moves towards the direction where he can use something like `MyDownloadListenerClass implements DownloadListener<AdListData>`

Comment: Oh, is `getDownloadCompleteState()` part of a generic interface? Sorry, I don't have any experience with Android programming...

Comment: No its not a generic interface, `onPostExecute` is but you get to define the input class types.

Comment: I think it is what I need. Can you give some code example please?

Answer (score 0):

Why you are making life too complicated..

Ever heard about `Moduler Code`, `Interfaces`, `Abstract class`es???

I ll suggest you to write one `Interface` or `Abstract class` over your `AdListData` and `AnotherClass`..  (I am assuming they share `IS A` relationship..) 
If not.. write two diff `AsyncTask`s for those.. and if they share common code you can use functions like utility functions..
doing this your code will be much more readable and simple..

now, to ans your question I ll just write some snippet..

```
public class Test {
    int data;

    public static <T extends Object> void foo(ArrayList<T> l) {
        T firstObj = l.get(0);

        if (firstObj != null) {
            if (firstObj instanceof Test) {
                System.out.println("yay.. I am list of test obj " + l);
            } else {
                System.out.println("m just another list.. :( " + l);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return data + "";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Test> l = new ArrayList<Test>();

        Test t1 = new Test();
        t1.data = 1;

        Test t2 = new Test();
        t2.data = 2;

        Test t3 = new Test();
        t3.data = 3;

        Test t4 = new Test();
        t4.data = 4;

        l.add(t1);
        l.add(t2);
        l.add(t3);
        l.add(t4);

        foo(l);

        ArrayList<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        l2.add(1);
        l2.add(2);
        l2.add(3);
        l2.add(4);
        foo(l2);
    }
}
```